# Why doesn't Kendo Datasource transmit the "take" parameter?

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

This is my code:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: getMembersUrl,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "get"
        }
    },
    serverPaging: true,
    pageSize: 2,
    schema: {
        data: "Data",
        total: "Total",
    }
});
```

When I call read on the datasource, it doesn't send the `pagesize` or `take` (I tried both) as part of the request. I am really scratching my head on this one.

Comment: There is no `take` property on the Kendo UI DataSource object. [Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource).

Comment: Is the widget using this dataSource configured for paging?

Comment: I am using a grid and yes, it is. Even just using it by itself (calling read on the dataSource) doesn't send the pagesize. 

According to the documentation `take=pageSize` (and I tried both)

Comment: You haven't identified the `pageSize`. Please post the code you used to configure your grid.

Comment: In simplifying the code to post here, I removed "autoBind" in my grid - which fixed it. Thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine and it sends `take` as expected. If you run:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "fake",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "get"
        }
    },
    serverPaging: true,
    pageSize: 2,
    schema: {
        data: "Data",
        total: "Total",
    }
});
```

And define a button and a handler for triggering the read:

```
<button id="read" class="k-button">Read</button>

$("#read").on("click", function() {
    console.log("About to fetch data");
    dataSource.fetch();
});
```

As here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/34qe4oks/

You will see in the browser console that it actually sends the request:

[image]

If you don't see the request is very likely because you are not actually reading from the DataSource (remember that the Grid DataSource is read when the Grid finishes its initialization)